# Stream Provider using custom model class to listen to firestore real time changes

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Almost all the example on stream provider using a model class, updates data by calling a method of the model class that encloses the `StreamController.sink` with the updated value (like an incremented integer). This method is then called through some `onPressed` event in the UI using `Provider.of(context)`. Can't this be achieved through `ChangeNotifier`? How is such an implementation going to listen to a real time change, say in a `Firestore collection` query snapshot stream?

I tried listening to the firestore stream directly using,

```
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(      
      value: Firestore.instance.collection('orders/' +  _auth.userID + '/orders').snapshots(),
      child: UIMain())
```

But I dont want to use this stream directly. I wish to create a custom stream using my own model class, that can provide the name of all the documents in this collection in real time, query another collection based on document ID from this collection and provide that data as a stream too, without pressing a button every time.

I hope someone could help with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own service and mappers to achieve the desired solution -

Firstly modal your data

product.dart

```
class Order {
  String id;
  String price;
  String name;

  Order({this.id, this.price, this.name,});

  factory Order.fromMap(Map snapshot,String id){
        id = id ?? '',
        price = snapshot['price'] ?? '',
        name = snapshot['name'] ?? '',
    }

  toJson() {
    return {
      "price": price,
      "name": name,
    };
  }
}
```

Then create your db service that will fetch the data from Firestore and map it accordingly.

order_service.dart

```
import 'package:model/order.dart';
        
class OrderService extends ChangeNotifier {
          final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
          
        
          Stream<List<Order>> fetchOrders(String merchID) {
    return _db.collection('merchants/' + merchID + '/orders').snapshots().map(
    (snapShot) => snapShot.documents
    .map(
    (document) => Order.fromMap(document.data, document.documentID))
    .toList());
    }
}
```

Then you can use this custom OrderService in the StreamProvider widget accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my StreamProvider widget, I have to provide fetchOrders as value or OrderService?

Comment: fetchOrders since that the one returning the stream.,  OrderService on another hand is a wrapper for  business logic for orders which may have other operations related to orders.

Comment: shouldn't the factory return Order?

Comment: Factory method inside the Order model is a virtual constructor that lets you build instance of Order model from snapshot thats is being recieved from firestore. OrdersService is helper class that lets you get data from firebase (document map) and parse it into Order model using Order.fromMap constructor. So the streamprovider should use the fetchOrders method.

Comment: You can do something like StreamProvider<List<Order>>.value( stream: OrderService().fetchOrders, child: UIMain())

Comment: I cannot call result.documents, there is no such getter; which is  strange.

Comment: Can you update that line with this - orders = result.map((doc) => Order.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)) .toList();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216579/discussion-between-gunjack-and-tanuj-wagh).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model class that has a getter method that returns a stream as such

```
class Order{
   final String name;
   Order({this.name});

   Stream<List<Order>> get orderList {
     return Firestore.instance.collection('orders/' +  _auth.userID + '/orders').snapshots().map((document) => Order(
          name: document.data['name']
       )
     ).toList();
}
```

And then Initialize your stream

```
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(      
  value: Order.orderList,
  child: UIMain())
)
```

Hope this helps :)